# How to enable Flash to play local content on a DVD?

Tags: flash, flowplayer, dvd

I'm creating a DVD for rural communities which packages an **offline** copy of a website (captured using httrack).  The original site contains many Vimeo embeds, and have replaced these with flowplayer pointing to mp4s on the DVD.

My problem is, the videos appear blank until the user enables local content like so:

**To specify trusted locations for developer testing**

1. On the Advanced panel, under Developer Tools, click Trusted location settings and then click Add.
2. Enter the location on your computer that contains the trusted content, or click Browse files or Browse for folder to locate the file or folder to trust. If you specify a folder instead of a file, then all of its contents (including subfolders) become trusted as well.
3. Click Confirm to add the domain, file, or folder to the list of trusted locations.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlayer/LSM/WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7ff0.html#WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7feb

I'm concerned that this makes the content much less accessible for user is a school environment.

Is there a way to whitelist my content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope, sorry, no can do. The best solution is using HTML5 with a flash fallback.  I selected http://videojs.com/.

You can't get around Flash security (thats good!)

I believe that other solutions for playing local content include:

- creating a flash projector,
- creating an adobe air app